# Getting hyperlink object out of the RowDataBound event

Tags: c#, gridview, asp.net-3.5

I need to programmatically disable certain hyperlinks in a gridview based upon the value of another column in the row.  I decided to handle the OnRowDataBound event to iterate and set them at runtime.  This mostly works, except I need to get to the HyperLink object.  How can I do it?

Here's where I'm at

```
    protected void IncomingTransfersGv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        // COLUMN OFFSET IN USE
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            object[] dataitems = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row.ItemArray;
            string carrier = (string)dataitems[7].ToString();

            if (carrier.ToLower() == "hand")
                (dataitems[8] as HyperLink).Enabled = false;//How can I get the hyperlink object here?  dataitems[8] only gives me the column's value..I don't need this
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**
The conversions aren't working.  I get an error about cannot convert type TableCell to Hyperlink.  HyperLinkField doesn't have an ID attribute.  Per an [article](http://www.codenewsgroups.net/aspnetwebcontrols/t9795-hyperlinkfield-findcontrol.aspx), I changed the hyperlinkfield to a template field, which is supposed to make this easier somehow, but unfortunetly the article doesn't say how...any ideas?

```
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Tracking">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" 
                    NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("trackingUrl", "{0}") %>' 
                    Text='<%# Eval("trackingNumber", "{0}") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try searching for the control.

```
HyperLink hl = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl(ControlName)
```

Comment: This works, but you have to convert it to a template field first.  With visual studio all I had to do is go into design view and it allowed me to just click a hyperlink to "convert field to a template field".  Then I have an ID to reference my HyperLink with.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 var hyperLink = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl(e.Row.Cells[8].Text)
```